# Selenium Webdriver false negative result for testing visibility of an element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing

I have an issue with Selenium Webdriver. I am running my automated test against a web application and have a test to check visibility of an element. When I run the same line of script in `CLI`, the element is found and `is_displayed()` returns "TRUE" but When I run it with other test cases through my Python IDE, `is_displayed()` returns `False`.

I tried implicit and explicit waits but wait is not the issue and the element is already loaded.

Here is the test case in my test script:

```
def test_image_element_icon_is_displayed(self):
    self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Image").is_displayed(),msg="Image is not displayed")
```

And this is script I run in CLI:

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Image").is_displayed()
```

Is there any way that I can prevent this false negative? Maybe changing the element selector I am currently using?

Here is the HTML of my Image element:

```
<div ng-click="applyDataElement(toolbarButton.type, toolbarButton.id)" class="frame-click ng-scope" ng-repeat="toolbarButton in toolbar">
                <div class="frame-box" ng-attr-id="{{toolbarButton.id}}" id="Image">
                    <div class="draggable-box">
                        <div bind-html-unsafe="toolbarButton.icon" class="draggable-icon ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></div>
                        <div class="draggable-label ng-binding">Image</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some `html` of the element?

Comment: What is the intended element here? the `div` with text *Image*? or the `div` with id *image*?

Comment: @Saifur The div with Image id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure this id cannot be unique since it is in `ng-repeat` and it's probably loading more than one elements with same id which is **not** safe to use.

With that being said and since, you also mentioned element load is not an issue, it safe to assume that the selector is probably returning some other element which is actually hidden. I experienced something similar before where selenium actually found the element which was hidden and was not the intended one. You can actually use `len()` with `find_elements_by_css_selector()` to see how many elements were returned.

Use `ng-attr-id="{{toolbarButton.id}}"` or whatever displayed on client in cojuntion with `[id='image'][ng-attr-id='something']` as cssSelector

Comment: Thanks, I used the whole css of Image element and it worked fine. However, I need to find a way to find a shorter unique attribute to find elements not the long css. @Saifur

Comment: @MahsaMortazavi You can. I usually do not worry about the long css as much as I do for long xpath unless you want some pretty codes. I do not know if long css would actually will hurt the execution time anyway

Answer (score 3):

The key difference between running the code in the Python terminal and running it as a script is that on terminal you have pauses/delays between every line you execute - this gives the page time to process asynchronous requests, update the DOM etc. In your test code, you need to **wait for the element to become visible**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
image = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Image")))
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, that's true. I have this issue before. However in this case, the element was loaded but #Image was not a unique selector.