# How to find element by atrribute using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to select text from the following html line:

```
<h3 data-reacid ='64'> text to select <h3>
```

I tried to use xpath. But for some reason, selenium can not find this element by xpath. I want to select the text by the 'data-reactid' attribute. I am not sure how to do this. I am using selenium with python.

Comment: The element being a `ReactJS` element the value of the attribute `data-reacid` possibly will be dynamic. Hence you may not be able to get `'64'`

Comment: It's actually static. I changed the xpath. It works now.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `64` is a stable value and does not change for this particular element and the attribute name is `data-reactid` (and not the `data-reacid` - looks like a typo):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@data-reactid = '64']").text
```

Equivalent CSS selector based solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3[data-reactid=64]").text
```

Of course, you need to account for the possible [timing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29463029/771848) and other situations like an [element being inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7534622/771848). This is specific to your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the answer might have a typo. find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@data-reactid = '64']" should be data-reactid =64. But it worked ! Can you explain why it doesnt't work when I use the xpath generated from the firefox inspect element option?

Answer (score 0):

***Latest code for getting value of any attribute of a tag or element:***

```
pros=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-element-name='facility-highlights']")
```